# value within object class is returning boolean false

Tags: php, class, object, woocommerce

I need some help please. I'm trying to grab the value of the applied_coupons public class and I can't for the life of me get it to display the value of the array within the public class for applied_coupons. I'm not a guru in the OOP world at all, and I'm honestly lost.

**The dump:**

```
  var_dump($woocommerce);

  object(Woocommerce)[357]
  public 'version' => string '2.0.14' (length=6)
  public 'plugin_url' => string 'url here' (length=57)
  public 'plugin_path' => string 'path here' (length=52)
  public 'template_url' => string 'template here' (length=12)
  public 'errors' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'messages' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'query' => 
    object(WC_Query)[266]
      public 'unfiltered_product_ids' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'filtered_product_ids' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'post__in' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'meta_query' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'layered_nav_post__in' => 
        array
          empty
      public 'layered_nav_product_ids' => 
        array
          empty`enter code here`
  public 'product_factory' => 
    object(WC_Product_Factory)[254]
  public 'cart' => 
    object(WC_Cart)[263]
      public 'cart_contents' => 
        array
          '35f4a8d465e6e1edc05f3d8ab658c551' => 
            array
              ...
      public 'applied_coupons' => 
        array
          0 => string 'free249' (length=7)
```

**What I need:**

The value from the applied_coupons class (free249)

**What I've tried:**

```
(Returns Null)
$coupon_code_found = $woocommerce->applied_coupons[0];
var_dump($coupon_code_found);

(Returns boolean false)
$coupon_code_found = $woocommerce->applied_coupons;
var_dump($coupon_code_found);

(Returns Null)
$coupon_code_found = $woocommerce->$cart->$WC_Cart->applied_coupons[0];
var_dump($coupon_code_found);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons;
```

Should return what you need.

When you type `$woocommerce->$cart` PHP tries to replace `$cart` with value of `$cart` variable which is not correct in this case. By skipping `$` you're telling PHP that you want to get variable with that name from given object.